# How can i check if a String equals a row in SQlite and print whole row?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

In my application i have a `SQliteDatabase` with the following structure and data

(it's just an example)

```
ID_CLI        NAME_CLI    WHERE_CLI
2345           IGOR         LVIV
4566           OLEG         KIEV   
1234           GIAN         REGGIO
```

Now in my `MainActivity` i have a `EditText` and a `Button` so if i enter in `EditText 2345` and i'll press the `Button` i would that in `TextView` there will be print the `2345 IGOR LVIV`

Actually i have yet searched for some similar stuff online but haven't found anything that could solve my issue.

**Do you have any suggestion on how can i do?**

Here is my DataBase

```
public class DataBaseHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

private static DataBaseHandler sInstance;

private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "Clienti.db";

private static final String TABLE_CLIENTS = "clienti_table";
private static final String ID_CLI = "ID_CLI";
private static final String COD_CLI = "COD_CLI";
private static final String RS1_CLI = "RS1_CLI";

public static synchronized DataBaseHandler getInstance(Context context) {

    // Per inizializzare il db in altre activities inserire :
    // DataBaseHandler myDB;
    // myDB = DataBaseHandler.getInstance(this);

    if (sInstance == null) {
        sInstance = new DataBaseHandler(context.getApplicationContext());
    }
    return sInstance;
}

private DataBaseHandler(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 1);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    String CREATE_TABLE_CLIENTS = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + TABLE_CLIENTS + " (ID_CLI TEXT,COD_CLI TEXT,RS1 TEXT)";
    db.execSQL(CREATE_TABLE_CLIENTS);
 }

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int i, int i1) {
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_CLIENTS);
    onCreate(db);
}

public void insertCLI(String ID,String COD,String RS1){

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

    values.put(ID_CLI,ID);
    values.put(COD_CLI,COD);
    values.put(RS1_CLI,RS1);

    db.insertWithOnConflict(TABLE_CLIENTI, null, values, SQLiteDatabase.CONFLICT_REPLACE);
}

public Cursor getDataTable()
{
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    return db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_CLIENTS);
}
}
```

Comment: do you want to search `ID_CLI` for value `2345` and want to get that row?

Comment: Right but the value 2345 depends of what i have insert in to EditText so i have to check if there is in ID_CLI a value that equals to it and get all the row

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add this method inside your database handler class

```
public static String dbRawSearch(String id) {
   String dbString = "";
   SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
   String query = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_CLIENTS + " WHERE ID_CLI = " + id";
   //Cursor points to a location in your results
   Cursor c = db.rawQuery(query, null);
   //Move to the first row in your results
   c.moveToFirst();
   //Position after the last row means the end of the results
   while (!c.isAfterLast()) {
       if (c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("ID_CLI")) != null) {
           dbString += c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("ID_CLI")) + "   " + c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("NAME_CLI")) + "   " + c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("WHERE_CLI"));
           dbString += "\n";
       }
       c.moveToNext();
   }
   db.close();
   return dbString;
}
```

Then go to your activity, and after initializing the editText, button, and textView, do the following:

```
DataBaseHandler dbHandler = new DataBaseHandler(this);
String searchKeyword = "";
String result = "";
yourButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(yourEditText.getText().toString())) {
             searchKeyWord = yourEditText.getText().toString();
             result = dbHandler.dbRawSearch(searchKeyWord );
             if(result != null){
              yourTextView.setText(result);
             }
           }
        }
    });
```

Comment: I have edited my answer to display a raw rather than just a cell

Answer (score 0):

Add a method in your `DataBaseHandler` class

```
public Cursor getRowByIdCli(String idCli){

   SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
   return db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_CLIENTS + " WHERE ID_CLI = ? ", new String[]{idCli} );
}
```

Comment: are you able to use `getDataTable` method?

Comment: Yes i'm able to use it, can't understand where is the mistake on your code seems legit

Comment: Updated answer check now

Comment: Ok perfect now it's got it

Comment: So now i just have to check with the cursor if the String of EditText equals to position 0 of idCli string right?

Comment: This query will fetch row only with `idCli` value you provided in parameter. You have to get each column data from the each cursor position.